# json.stringify object and rename variables in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to serialize an object `o`, which has a method called, let's say, `a`. The object also holds a variable, which name is `_a`.

I now want to parse this object to a JSON string. But the JSON looks something like this:

```json
{
    "_a": "",
    ...
}
```

## Question

Is there a way, to **comfortably** remove/ replace the `_` character(s) (or any character(s)).

## What I have tried

1. The rename parameter of the JSON.stringify() method.
   1.1. Didn't work, because you can only return altered values and no keys.
2. Iterating all keys of an object, deleting them and creating a new renamed key, and assigning the value (see code below).
   2.1. This works, but is not really readable and nasty, when having "sub-object".

```js
Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    Object.defineProperty(o, key.replace("_", ""),
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, key));
    delete o[key];
});
```

Comment: As you said the object has a method named `a` and a property named `_a`, removing _ from the property name is possible but either the method will survive or the property.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you:

```js
let obj = {
  "_a": "",
  "b": "Test"
}

let result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  let newKey = key.replace('_', '')
  acc[newKey] = value
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: but that object also has a method named `_a`, with your method only one of these will survive.